# How to wrap Tablix table to fit page with dynamic columns?

Tags: reporting-services, .net-4.0

I'm using a tablix with dynamic columns to display test data and there can be 100+ columns of data. The report works well, but prints badly, with lots of white space.

Is there a way to have the Tablix wrap at the page width without a new page? The report is embedded in an .Net 4 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce the column size the maximum as you can.
Although the columns might look very small where people use in report Viewer they have the zoom option. When they print the result will look fine.

Don't forget to preview the report print result in report builder 3 by using the option "Print Layout". If your report goes across multiple pages in the "Print Layout" make ajustments like reducing font-size and column width.