# Is there a way to wrap a one-column table vertically to fit a page's width, empty space (markdown)

Tags: html, markdown

I have one-column table in markdown that is very long. As a result, it uses several pages, and leaves a lot of white space. Is there a way to have this column "wrap" vertically until it uses all the white space in a page before going on to the next page? I can take answers in markdown or HTML, if the HTML is fairly basic.

```markdown
| Column Header |
| ------------- |
| Item 1        |
| Item 2        |
| Item 3        |
|      .        |
|      .        |
|      .        |
| Item i        |
|      .        |
|      .        |
|      .        |
| Item n        |
```

The two "similar" questions recommended by SO are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003845/how-to-wrap-tablix-table-to-fit-page-with-dynamic-columns) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749201/empty-space-for-one-columns-width-with-flexbox), but former is for Tablix, which I'm not using, and the latter creates columns, but they do not wrap vertically to fill a page. That is, it does not go from top to bottom of a page repeatedly until filling up a page before going to the next.